# Bootstrap 3 carousel white background when sliding

Tags: html, css, slider, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Everytime the carousel slides, a white background appears aboven the image.

http://jan.tczutendaal.be/project.php?term=34&project=61

How is this possible?

Comment: Every time slide scrolls BT adds `.left` to the class `.item` now the problem is in `.left` class there you wrote 43%; better change the class name.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi in bootstrap carousel every time it scrolls the item it add class `.left` or `right` according to your navigation to `.item` in your case you wrote style for .left class like

```
#project .left {
    background: url("../images/arrow_left_home.png") no-repeat scroll center center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 38px;
    top: 43%;
}
```

there you having top value please change the class name or top value..it will work.hope it will help

Comment: I'll try this later at home, then I'll accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

From my (very recent) experience: MAKE SURE you haven't used any "crafty" global `.left` or `.right` classes. In my case, the problem was such a misplaced global `.right` class, with `float: right;` assigned to it.

Comment: true, also you can use 'pull-left/right' in Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing `white space` because of `top` value define in the following class.

Remove the `top` property and the bug will be fixed.

```
#project .left 
{
top: 43%; /*disable this property*/
}
```